# Automatically create a 2D array simulations map

Tags: java, image-processing, multidimensional-array, agent-based-modeling

So I'm working on a agent based simulation and I'm going to use a 2D array which could be 500x5000 or 1000x1000. The actual simulation will consist of walls which make up rooms. The problem I don't want to manually insert each wall because this could take very long.

Is there a way where I can create a simple 2D image of a map and have the program read this image and insert the walls into the 2D array based on the image.

Regards

Comment: Of course, use a png (lossless compression), read in as a BufferedImage, and examine the pixels. What is the question?

Comment: Can I assign each pixel a numerical value or can I only read RGB values ?

Comment: RGB values are numerical...

Comment: I think I need to follow some tutorials. Do you recommend any ?